# How to solve Password Management - Password in configuration

Tags: password-encryption, fortify

Hi I am using HP fortify to find all vulnerabilities of my App, and now i am trying to solve one that seems basic but I am not able to do it.

The problem is about password in configuration. I have an web application and inside of it in a properties file something like this.

```
somePassword=passwordPlainText
```

I agree this is wrong, then i try to obfuscate with several methods using http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html, OBS, CRYPT and ENC types. But I always get the same warning from fortify when i scan my code. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You may find the following answer helpful. I'm assuming this might be a database password, but the same concepts apply to accessing other types of accounts.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22817/how-to-encrypt-database-connection-credentials-on-a-web-server

Basic principle is that you want to avoid accidental leak of the credentials, and so put them in a place outside of code (where all developers will see it) and in a configuration file that is outside of the main code root and is carefully access controlled. Ideally, you can avoid passwords altogether by properly configuring database access according to user permissions.

*Note*: Fortify finds the password issue by basically [grepping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for "password" (and some variants). So other times this is false positive, if you just have a variable named "password" or a comment that mentions "password," but are not hard coding a password into the file.